# Removing the unwanted substrings from a series of strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of strings as given below

```
Tata Jaguor 1474 pSNL Series Car
Tata Nano Pro 5864 Series Car
Tata Indica 8586 k5478
Tata Nano 5864 E5478
Tata Bolero 8974 1567 Series
```

After stripping the unwanted string the resultant string  expecting is given respectively as follows

```
  Jaguor 1474
  Nano 5864 
  Indica 8586_k5478
  Nano 5864_E5478
  Bolero 8974_1567
```

i tried the following code to do this,but not got the expected result

```
Vehiclename.replace("Tata ","").replace("Series","").replace("Pro ","").replace(" Car","")
```

Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: You tagged your question with `regex`. I'd say that that's a better way to do it, if you can formulate rules. You want to include the third part if it contains numbers? Adding the underscore could be done separately.

Comment: iam not good in regex,if you don't mind and time allows please help me

Comment: Did you try using your attempt using proper casing? In your example, you have `Tata ` but you are trying to replace `Tata  ` (two white spaces), `series` in your example is written differently and the same goes for `Pro`.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ: Going through the edit history it would seem that the question has been edited.

Comment: @user1654136 First off, your approach would work fairly well if your  examples are that limited (assuming that you fix the assignment issue mentioned by npinti). Otherwise, I'd suggest that you start looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for python regexes. That's how you learn.

Comment: Why not use `re.sub`?  Example: `>>> Vehiclename = 'Tata Nano Pro 5864 Series Car'
>>> re.sub(r'\b(?:Tata |Pro | Car|Series)\b', '', Vehiclename)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reobj = re.compile(r"Tata ([\w ]+\d+).*?$", re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
result = reobj.sub(r"\1", subject)
```

http://rubular.com/r/jvvtCjlTKy

```
Jaguor 1474
Nano Pro 5864
Indica 8586 k5478
Nano 5864 E5478
Bolero 8974 1567
```

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with my comment:

In your example, you have `Tata` but you are trying to replace `Tata<space><space>`. `series` in your example is written differently and the same goes for `Pro`, digging the documentation for the [`String replace()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

> The method replace() returns a copy of the string in which the
>   occurrences of old have been replaced with new, optionally restricting
>   the number of replacements to max.

In your case, you do not seem to be doing anything with the returned value, this should work:

```
Vehiclename = Vehiclename.replace("Tata ","").replace("Series","").replace("Pro ","").replace(" Car","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the regular expression for you:

```
'\s.*[0-9]{4}'
```

You can implement in python. This isnt removing what you are 'not' looking for instead giving what you are looking for.