# automate the extraction of a pattern from a series of strings

Tags: python, pandas, text

How can I automate the extraction of a pattern from a series of strings such that I only end up with the expression without any strings after the second occurnce of the underscore:

```
s = pd.Series(['abc_def_(123)', 'aerbc_dehjf_(12358)', 'aerbc_df_(89'])
```

I am expectign to have an output like this:

```
new_s = ['abc_def','aerbc_dehjf','aerbc_df']
```

The most similar question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197775/removing-the-unwanted-substrings-from-a-series-of-strings), but it is not really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
import re
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['abc_def_(123)', 'aerbc_dehjf_(12358)', 'aerbc_df_(89',"abc_AD"])
list1=[]
for i in s:
    m=re.search(r"((^[a-zA-Z]*_[a-zA-Z]*))",i)
    if m:
        print m.group()
        list1.append( m.group(2))

print list1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['abc_def', 'aerbc_dehjf', 'aerbc_df', 'abc_AD']
```

Comment: can you please explain the pattern  "((^.*_.*)_)"? some of the elements in my series have got just one underscore "abc_AD"

Comment: @owise i just changed the pattern right now to include the one  underscore case pls refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html link for what i have done